# MWPhotoBrowser display caption in grid view

Tags: caption, mwphotobrowser

I know MWPhotoBrowser supports captions on MWPhoto.  However the captions are not displayed while the grid is being displayed.  Is there a setting to display captions in grid view?

Answer (score 0):

MWPhotoBrowser doesn't display captions in the grid view. This behaviour can't be found in the documentation or the GitHub page of it